# Converting text from EditText to html and back loses formatting

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an EditText called `content`. Inside it is some formatted text. I then want to switch between seeing the formatted text and the html by doing :

```
if(!showHtml)
    content.setText(Html.fromHtml(content.getText().toString()), BufferType.SPANNABLE);
else
    content.setText(Html.toHtml(content.getText()));
```

If the formatted text is "test **test**", the html comes out as `<p>test <b>test </b></p>` which is fine, but when going back, the formatting is lost and I get "test test".

If the formatted text is "**test** test", the html comes out as `<p><b>test</b> test</p>`, which is correct once again. However, the text obtained when going back is "**test test**".

So what it looks like is that the formatting of the first word is applied to the rest of the text (I've tested it on longer strings).

Has anyone encountered this before, and how could I go about solving this?

**Edit 1** It seems that with EditText.setText(), it automatically uses the Editable flag and completely ignores my request for a Spannable. Could this be where the problem is coming from?

Comment: try `content.setText(content.getText());`. .**toString** will erase all the formatting.

Comment: `Html.fromHtml` takes a string, so I have to use the toString. Also, in that particular part, I am sending it the raw html, so there is no formatting to remove. But thanks for trying to help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was being a fool. I had completely forgotten that I had a `TextWatcher` that modified the styles that were applied. All I needed to do was set a flag telling it not to modify the styles if it was after converting from html.